# Event not call while use same event

Tags: magento-1.9

I have used `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` in two extension.
But even call one at a time. Can anyone have an idea why this happens? And how I can call both extension observer function.

Detail code: 
1st extension at app\code\local\Adit\Appaccess\etc\config.xml

```
<events>
  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> 
    <observers>
      <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler>
        <type>model</type>
        <class>appaccess/observer</class>
        <method>ordersuccessafter</method>
        <args></args>
      </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler>
    </observers>
  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
</events>
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\d8\app\code\local\Adit\Appaccess\Model\Observer.php

```
class Adit_Appaccess_Model_Observer{
public function ordersuccessafter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
    echo '<pre>';print_r($order->getId());exit;
}}
```

2nd extension at \app\code\local\Adit\Bundlepromo\etc\config.xml

```
<events>
  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> 
    <observers>
      <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler> 
        <type>model</type>
        <class>bundlepromo/observer</class>
        <method>salesordersaveafter</method>
        <args></args> 
      </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler>
    </observers>
  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
</events>
```

\app\code\local\Adit\Bundlepromo\Model\Observer.php

```
class Adit_Bundlepromo_Model_Observer{
public function salesordersaveafter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
    echo '<pre>';print_r($order->getId());exit;
}}
```

In above case Only Bundlepromo\Model\Observer.php will processed.

Comment: You can add as many observers on an event as you like and all the observer functions will be fired on event dispatch. Can you please provide some code to look at.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya I have added detail code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are using same identifier(tag name) for both of you observers. Change them and it will work with both the observers.

```
<events>
  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> 
    <observers>
      <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_ordersuccessafter><!-- change this -->
        <type>model</type>
        <class>appaccess/observer</class>
        <method>ordersuccessafter</method>
        <args></args>
      </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_ordersuccessafter>
    </observers>
  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
</events>
```

And

```
<events>
  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> 
    <observers>
      <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_salesordersaveafter><!-- should not be duplicate --> 
        <type>model</type>
        <class>bundlepromo/observer</class>
        <method>salesordersaveafter</method>
        <args></args> 
      </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_salesordersaveafter>
    </observers>
  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
</events>
```

Also, you should remove exit from code, it will prevent any further code to be executed.

Comment: I have try this But after run "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_ordersuccessafter" . Another observer was not called.
Menace in your code, 1st observer was called.
I have removed exit.

Comment: Did you remove exit from your observer code?

Comment: Yes, I have removed it.